# What is the main difference between hmc and backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

As I know working in **hmc** is better than working in **backoffice** .Then why in **hybris 6.0** , **hmc** is deprecated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find bellow the main differences between **HMC** and **Backoffice** from the official demo of Hybris :

[image]

[image]

Actually most of this new features are transparent to public users, but they are very interesting to developers.

Personally, I like **Backoffice** because it's so extensible and highly customizable, it possess a very rich library of widgets and so easy to create and customize your own widgets, it support `AngularJS` and `Application Orchestrator` which is much preferable over than the old `ZK framework` ...

> **HMC** is already deprecated and it's de-release is planned for 2018.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the main purpose is to get rid off all other cockpits for business employees leaving only one with different perspectives and more customizable widgets. The idea itself looks good. But purely for admin/developer purposes backoffice is still looks worse, more laggy and less convinient than hmc. No right mouse button. You cannot even open several popups and freely switch between them, since only the last one is always active. For business users it is supposed to be ok, but for the admins/developers it will be nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are used to **hmc**, it is hard to imagine working with **backoffice**. The main advantage of **backoffice**, is that it is highly customizable. In **hmc** you have a limited set of controls to use, while in **backoffice**, you should be capable of creating your own. For example cool and special pickers, editors, views, diagrams and all sorts of widgets. Also it is mobile friendly :)

The main real good thing for me is the integrated **SOLR** search.

Nevertheless **hmc** is deprecated, you can still add it as an extension and use it. This is really good, because it gives you the space and time to migrate you and your users to **backoffice**.

More information you can find in the
[change log](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c17707686691014b72a8fb745de355a.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons to replace the hMC.

- it's hard ad expensive to customize
- it looks too "technical" for business teams which are supposed to use it.

But note that contrary at what SAP currently say, the backoffice do not cover all features of the hMC.

For example :

- you can't search on custom field without doing customization
- you can't create object with new custom field without customizing the wizard
- you can't do multiple selection, to delete a bunch of objects for example